# Algorithm in thrust/cudpp to find kth smallest element

Tags: cuda, nvidia, thrust, cudpp

I am looking for an implemention of kth smallest element algorithm in thrust/cudapp. I Googled for it but dont seem to find it. Does any one know if there exists such an algorithm?

I saw that there is reordering but it does not say kth smallest.

Comment: @MrFooz, sheesh, Quickselect is O(N) on average.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660978/how-long-does-thrust-take-to-sort-1-million-floats) to your other question.

Answer (score 1):

Thrust does not currently provide the selection algorithm (i.e. `std::nth_element` in the STL) though it's on our radar and there's [good evidence](http://www.moderngpu.com/select/radixselect.html) that selection can be done quickly on the GPU.  Your only recourse right now is to sort the data with `thrust::sort` or `thrust::sort_by_key` (or their `stable_` variants) and then pick the appropriate element(s).  Sorting primitive types (e.g. `int`, `float`, `char`, `double`) in Thrust is implemented with a very fast radix sort code, so the absolute performance will still be quite good, albeit not as efficient as a [specialized selection method](http://www.moderngpu.com/select/radixselect.html).